# Cassandra : Improper copy command

Tags: cassandra

I wanna import CSV file from https://www.kaggle.com/fernandol/countries-of-the-world to ma cassandra in vagrant. The command I use is

```
COPY countries (Country, Region, Population, Area, Pop. Density, Coastline, Net Migration, Infant Mortality, GDP, Literacy, Phones, Arable, Crops, Other, Climate, Birthrate, Deathrate, Agriculture, Industry, Service) FROM '/vagrant/countries.csv' WITH HEADER = true;
```

However I got error message

```
Improper COPY command.
```

Any idea what did I do wrong? I have keyspace countries. Thank you. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the table structure?

Comment: Is `countries` a keyspace or a table?
`Copy` command takes table name after it

Comment: Column names should not have spaces and dot (.).... change your column names also for upper case column names it should be enclosed in double quotes

Comment: @AlexOtt Mis94 undefined_variables thank you so much your solutions solve my probleem